# Traversing up and finding a child element with attribute equal to a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list `UL` that contains an element article that has an attribute `data-level`. I am traversing in Javascript through the articles. I am adding a replyto symbol to comments that have a `data-level` larger than 1, but to get the username of the parent, I need to traverse the comment list up and find an article element that has `data-level="0"` and get the username from that element.

I can't use jquery `closest()` because it doesn't check inside the element. If I use `parent().parent()` it will run closest() on the parent, which is also not good.

How can I run a `closest()` function or something familiar on the article element (red arrow in the image) to find the first article element above it that has its attribute equals to 0 (`data-level="0"`).

Here's an the HTML code:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <article itemprop="comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" data-user-id="28" id="comment-40" data-comment-id="40" class="comment-wrapper" data-level="0">
        <header>
            <p class="comment-title"> <span class="submitted-by"><span itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">yariv</span></span><span class="karma" title="Karma"><span class="fa fa-star"></span>0</span> •
                <meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z">
                <time class="date-submitted" datetime="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z">7 months ago</time>
                </span>
            </p>
        </header>
        <div class="comment-content">
            <p class="comment-body" itemprop="text">fgdfg </p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-options"><span data-already-voted="false" class="upvote"><span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="upvote-num" itemprop="upvoteCount">1</span></span><span class="reply" data-user-id="28" data-comment-id="40">Reply</span><span class="flag-comment">Flag</span>
        </div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
    </article>
</li>
<li>
    <article itemprop="comment" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment" data-user-id="28" id="comment-42" data-comment-id="40" class="comment-wrapper" data-level="2">
        <header>
            <p class="comment-title"> <span class="submitted-by"><span itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">yariv</span></span><span class="karma" title="Karma"><span class="fa fa-star"></span>0</span> •
                <meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z">
                <time class="date-submitted" datetime="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z">7 months ago</time>
                </span>
            </p>
        </header>
        <div class="comment-content">
            <p class="comment-body" itemprop="text">fgdfg </p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-options"><span data-already-voted="false" class="upvote"><span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span><span class="upvote-num" itemprop="upvoteCount">1</span></span><span class="reply" data-user-id="28" data-comment-id="40">Reply</span><span class="flag-comment">Flag</span>
        </div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
    </article>
</li>
</ul>
```

Note: There can be several comments with `data-level="0"` and I need the closest one above the article I am currently checking. In other words. For an  `<article>` element, I need to find the closest (from above) `<article>` element that exists above it inside an `li` element that it's attribute `data-level` equals to zero.

Comment: also, can you clearly state what you are trying to select? very words. wow

Comment: can you post your code to understood it clearly

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not a robot, it takes me a minute to do it.

Comment: @ButaniVijay yes sure. I posted it. Thanks

Comment: Where is UL in code?

Comment: @IdanShechter: It's just odd not to just do the full edit all at once.

Comment: @ButaniVijay added

Comment: If I undestand it correctly you can select it using `.parents('[data-level="0"]')`

Comment: @jcubic But there can be several data-level="0", I need the closest one above the article.

Comment: @jcubic: No, the structure's more awkward than that unfortunately.

Comment: Try `.parents('[data-level="0"]').eq(0)` it will select first parent that have data-level = 0

Comment: @jcubic OK I will try that.

Comment: @jcubic $('article[data-comment-id="47"]').parents('[data-level="0"]').eq(0) return no element (aka n.fn.init[0]) and comment Id in my app has a parent li element that has an article with data-level="0"

Comment: @jcubic: It's not an ancestor, it's a cousin (the descendant of a parent's sibling).

Comment: @jcubic thanks, but you didn't expect me and my bad English to know that :) Thanks all of you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `closest` to get the `li` around the reply, and then `prevAll` with a `:has([data-level=0])` filter, and then `first` to get the nearest (`prevAll` returns them in order of nearness rather than the usual document order):

```
var main = startingElement
  .closest("li")
  .prevAll(":has([data-level=0])")
  .first()
  .find("[data-level]");
```

Simplified example:

```js
// Get our starting point:
var startingElement = $("#start");

// Find the "nearest" data-level=0
var main = startingElement
  .closest("li")
  .prevAll(":has([data-level=0])")
  .first()
  .find("[data-level]");

// Show what we got
console.log(main.text());
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div data-level="0">first level 0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="1">first level 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="2">first level 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="0">second level 0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="1">second level 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="2" id="start">second level 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="0">third level 0</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="1">third level 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div data-level="2">third level 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note how our starting point was the `li` two siblings away from the one containing `data-level="0"`, but we skipped the one in-between because it didn't match the `:has` condition.

Comment: I glad that you understand my question, my English is not that good. I'm checking your code now.

Comment: @IdanShechter: I've seen *much* worse English. :-)

Comment: This works, thank you for understand, it was hard for me to explain. Genius 459K of pure skill. Thanks!!

Comment: I will learn the code also to understand it better for next time.

Comment: This is the final code I used to get the username from that level 0 comment:  $(this).closest("li").prevAll(":has([data-level=0])").first().find("[data-level]").eq(0).find("span[itemprop='name']").html().trim();

Answer (score 1):

To add a reply widget to each comment as mentioned, I'd do something like this. Keep in mind that each related comment references the original w/ [data-comment-id]

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-level][data-level!='0']").each(function() { 
        var id = $(this).data('commentId'),
          $comment = $('#comment-'+ id +''),
          author = $comment.find('[itemprop="name"]').text();

        $('<span> Reply to: </span>')
          .appendTo($(this))
          .append($('<a href="#">'+author+'</a>'));  
    });     
})
```